# Can I go back and reject the offer?

Tags: resignation

I have signed a job offer for a subsidiary of my current company.

The offer states that my new offer ***is contingent upon your resignation from*** the mother company.

Thus, it means that if I decided to go back now and don't resign from the mother company I still work for the mother company?

Or signing this offer I have already resign from the main company?

Comment: This is a legal question. Only a lawyer with experience in labour law in your location and the specifics of your situation can inform you of your options.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you still want the job with the subsidiary company?

Comment: I dont want the job with the subsidiary company, I want to reject the offer as I have thought it is not convenient for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get the obvious out of the way first: next time, think about whether a job is "convenient" for you *before* accepting the offer.

The situation right now is that you've dug yourself into a big hole. You can potentially try getting yourself out of the hole by playing "legal tricks" around the exact wording of your offer; whether that will work or not isn't something we can advise you on. However, it is pretty much guaranteed to do one thing: to let everyone involved with the whole process know you are unreliable - and that's a good way to damage your long-term prospects, or possibly to end up without a job at all.

So, what can you do about it? Own up to your mistake and open an honest dialogue with all involved parties. Perhaps they'll agree to let you stay at the parent company.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is more complex than the normal job switch.

If you were switching companies and you decided the day after signing an offer letter that you don't want to take the new job you would tell your new company "I changed my mind". There are many questions on this site regarding how to back out of that situation. The longer you wait, the more likely the new company will be mad because they can lose their second choice, and they may start spending money in anticipation of your arrival.

If you never told the current company about your signed offer letter, your job is most likely safe. The new company would only contact the old company as part of the background investigation. And if the company has a third party provide employment info, your manager is unlikely to be told.

The two companies have a complex financial and legal relationship, but for many employees the switching between them is supposed to be easy. But for the companies the legal issues mean that they want to avoid having a person employed by both companies, thus the absolute requirement that you resign from one before working for the other.

Your complication is in the relationship between the two companies. Depending on that structure, returning the letter may have caused HR in the parent company to start the off-boarding process. For all you know within a few hours of returning the form, your current manager may have been notified.

Even if the process hasn't started, the attempt to stop the switch to the new job may cause the subsidiary to complain via official channels that the parent company block the transfer. That isn't what happened, but it doesn't mean that they can't complain. If they do file a complaint, your manger will find out.

Your best course of action depends on how much risk you are wanting to take. The gamble is: have you damaged your current job by accepting the offer? If the problem is the tasks with the new job, then you might think about only staying in the position for a year, and then finding a position back with the main company, or another job within the subsidiary.